# Help Identify this game: place wooden barriers try to get across

Tags: identify-this-game

When I was younger I had a cool game, that I forget the name of, and would like to re-acquire.

It was a small wooden board, with a grid of squares on it. There were two players, and each turn, you could move your piece, or place a barrier in one of the slits. You couldn't completely block your opponent, but you had to try to get to the other side of the board before they did.

Does anybody know what this game was called?

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. not sure how I didnt find those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love [Quoridor](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/624/quoridor).

[image: Quoridor]

............